# PHP mail() from email and replyto adds server address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I currently have a php script to send emails from Ubuntu server with sendmail.

```
$to = $sendTo;
$subject = $subjectPrefix . $subject;
$txt = $message;
$headers = array(
  "From: ". $email,
  "Reply-To: ".$email,
  "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8",
  "MIME-Version: 1.0",
  "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
);
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){
  echo "sent";
}
else {
  echo "failed";
}
```

The emails send fine but always go into spam and have the server address attached to the email, for exmaple: "input@email.com"@ip-###-##-##-###.eu-west-2.compute.internal

How would i go about setting this to only show the input email and not go into spam?

Comment: Observation: `implode` can be avoided if you restructure the array (PHP 7.2.0+) `$headers = array('From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the mailserver you're using to send your email does not belong to the domain of the sender, and is therefore not a 'trusted' source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMTP server of your email's domain. For example, if you want to use email from Google's Gmail Service as `From address` , you have to use the Gmail SMTP server.

So, you can add SMTP email rely for SendMail. How to do it you may read [here](https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay)

Also, you can install SMTP client `msmtp` and configure PHP for using it. Instructions [here](https://codingproductivity.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/configuring-msmtp-on-ubuntu-16-04-again/)

At last, if you don`t want to configure your server, you can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library.